# 7-Segment display with printf and multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

So my problem lies with my process_digit function I believe. The cases I don't think are indexing properly through each iteration of the 1's and 0's and so when I type in an input such as 4 i get an incorrect output. I'm not sure if the case
statements are backwards or what's happening but essentially I think they are not correct.

```
//input is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
//output should be        _   _        _   _   _   _   _   _
//                     |  _|  _|  |_| |_  |_    | |_| |_| | |
//                     | |_   _|    |  _| |_|   | |_|   | |_|
//output is              _    _        _   _    _  _    _   _
//                     | _|   _|  |_|  |_  |_   |  |_|  |_| ||
//                     | |_   _|  |    _|  |_|  |  |_|  _|  |_|
//
```

```css
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_DIGITS 10

void clear_digits_array(void);
void process_digit(int digit, int position);
void print_digits_array(void);
char digits[3][MAX_DIGITS*4];
const int array[MAX_DIGITS][7]={{1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0},{1,0,1,1,1,0,1},{1,0,1,1,0,1,1},{0,1,1,1,0,1,0},{1,1,0,1,0,1,1},{1,1,0,1,1,1,1},{1,0,1,0,0,1,0},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,0,1,1},};


void clear_digits_array(void){
    int j=0,i=0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<MAX_DIGITS*4;j++){
            digits[i][j]='\0';
        }
    }
}

void process_digit(int digit, int position){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++){
        if(array[digit][i]==1){
            switch(i){
                case 0: digits[0][1+position*4]='_';
                    break;
                case 1: digits[1][0+position*4]='|';
                    break;
                case 2: digits[1][2+position*4]='|';
                    break;
                case 3: digits[1][1+position*4]='_';
                    break;
                case 4: digits[2][0+position*4]='|';
                    break;
                case 5: digits[2][2+position*4]='|';
                    break;
                case 6: digits[2][1+position*4]='_';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
void print_digits_array(void){
    int a=0,b=0;
    printf("                                                                                       ");
    for(a=0;a<3;a++){
        printf("                                                                                       ");
        for(b=0;b<MAX_DIGITS*4;b++)
            printf("%c",digits[a][b]);
        printf("                                                                                       ");
    }
    printf("                                                                                       ");
}
int main(void) {
    char character_number='\0';
    int a=0;
    
    clear_digits_array();
    printf("Enter a number:");
    while ((character_number=getchar())!='\n') {
        int number=MAX_DIGITS;
        switch(character_number){
            case '0': number=0;
                break;
            case '1': number=1;
                break;
            case '2': number=2;
                break;
            case '3': number=3;
                break;
            case '4': number=4;
                break;
            case '5': number=5;
                break;
            case '6': number=6;
                break;
            case '7': number=7;
                break;
            case '8': number=8;
                break;
            case '9': number=9;
                break;
            default: printf("%c ignored", character_number);
        }
        if(a==0){
            process_digit(number,a);
            a++;
        }
    }
    print_digits_array();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's how I figured it out. @Mescarra you were correct in saying that I should clear the array with blank spaces rather than a null character. However, that only solved half of the problems. For this to work correctly, when the print function was called, there were two \n needed. One between the rows and one between the columns to apply a space where was needed to align the characters correctly. Here's what I ended up getting to work properly. If there's a better way of doing so than please share, would love to know!

```css
//
//output should be        _   _        _   _   _   _   _   _
//                     |  _|  _|  |_| |_  |_    | |_| |_| | |
//                     | |_   _|    |  _| |_|   | |_|   | |_|

#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_DIGITS 10

void clear_digits_array(void);
void process_digit(int digit, int position);
void print_digits_array(void);
char digits[3][MAX_DIGITS*4];
const int array[MAX_DIGITS][7]={{1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0},{1,0,1,1,1,0,1},{1,0,1,1,0,1,1},{0,1,1,1,0,1,0},{1,1,0,1,0,1,1},{1,1,0,1,1,1,1},{1,0,1,0,0,1,0},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,0,1,1},};



void clear_digits_array(void){
    int j=0,i=0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<MAX_DIGITS*4;j++){
            digits[i][j]=' ';
        }
    }
}

void process_digit(int digit, int position){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++){
        if(array[digit][i]==1){
            switch(i){
                case 0: digits[0][1+position*4]='_';
                    break;
                case 1: digits[1][0+position*4]='|';
                    break;
                case 2: digits[1][2+position*4]='|';
                    break;
                case 3: digits[1][1+position*4]='_';
                    break;
                case 4: digits[2][0+position*4]='|';
                    break;
                case 5: digits[2][2+position*4]='|';
                    break;
                case 6: digits[2][1+position*4]='_';
                    break;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
void print_digits_array(void){
    int a=0,b=0;
    for(a=0;a<3;a++){
        for(b=0;b<MAX_DIGITS*4;b++)
            printf("%c",digits[a][b]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main(void) {
    char character_number='\0';
    int a=0;
    
    clear_digits_array();
    printf("Enter a number:");
    while ((character_number=getchar())!='\n') {
        int number=MAX_DIGITS;
        switch(character_number){
            case '0': number=0;
                break;
            case '1': number=1;
                break;
            case '2': number=2;
                break;
            case '3': number=3;
                break;
            case '4': number=4;
                break;
            case '5': number=5;
                break;
            case '6': number=6;
                break;
            case '7': number=7;
                break;
            case '8': number=8;
                break;
            case '9': number=9;
                break;
            default: number=' ';
        }
        if(a<MAX_DIGITS){
            process_digit(number,a);
            a++;
        }
    }
    print_digits_array();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have to actually print white spaces (`printf(" ");`) if the line segment is inactive (instead of not printing anything), otherwise 7-segment display will show kind of messy. Here's an ugly code that does the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_DIGITS 10

const int array[MAX_DIGITS][7]={{1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0},{1,0,1,1,1,0,1},{1,0,1,1,0,1,1},{0,1,1,1,0,1,0},{1,1,0,1,0,1,1},{1,1,0,1,1,1,1},{1,0,1,0,0,1,0},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,0,1,1},};

void print_number(int num)
{
    //First line
    if (array[num][0]) printf(" _ ");

    printf("\n");

    //Second line
    if (array[num][1])
        printf("|");
    else
        printf(" ");

    if (array[num][3])
        printf("_");
    else
        printf(" ");

    if (array[num][2]) printf("|");

    printf("\n");

    //Third line
    if (array[num][4])
        printf("|");
    else
        printf(" ");

    if (array[num][6])
        printf("_");
    else
        printf(" ");

    if (array[num][5]) printf("|");

    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    int a=0;

    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (a>=0 && a <= 9){
        print_number(a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

To accomplish this with your code, you could just initialize the `digits` array with white spaces instead of null characters (`\0`) like so:

```
void clear_digits_array(void){
    int j=0,i=0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<MAX_DIGITS*4;j++){
            digits[i][j]=' ';
        }
    }
}
```

And then you should print line breaks to separate lines, like so:

```
void print_digits_array(void){
    int a=0,b=0;
    for(a=0;a<3;a++){
        for(b=0;b<MAX_DIGITS*4;b++)
            printf("%c",digits[a][b]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And that should do it!

Comment: Ok, I editted the program above to show the exact output I'm getting. I'm not exactly sure as to how I would implement your idea seing as each of those marks are being stored in an int array that prints them out at the end.

Comment: An easy way out is to initialize the `digits` array with with white spaces instead of the null character (`\0`). I'll edit my answer to show you how.